# GIT from source: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: linux, git, https, curl, openssl

Due to me not having root rights, I compiled git from source locally. My distro is OpenSUSE 13.1.
Googling the error `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`

It was suggested that curl is not configured properly. However, using curl to access https://example.com works just fine.

Another suggestion was that curl wasnt linked properly to git during configuring and making git.

The steps I took to get where I am now:

Installed Openssl-1.0.0t in my home.

```
./config --prefix=$HOME shared
make
make install
```

(completes without any errors)

Then I installed curl-7.48.0 in my home:

```
./buildconf
./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-ssl=$HOME

Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      enabled (libSSH2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  enabled
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     /etc/ssl/certs/
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     enabled (OpenLDAP)
  LDAPS support:    enabled
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS LDAP LDAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SCP SFTP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

make 
make install
```

(completes without any errors)

Thirdly I installed expat 2.1.1:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib -L$HOME/lib64" ./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

(completes without any errors)

Finally GIT 2.8.2:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I $HOME/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib -L$HOME/lib64" ./configure --with-curl=$HOME --with-openssl=$HOME --prefix=$HOME --with-expat=$HOME
make
make install
```

This too seems to go well with no warnings to be reported. I obviously overlooked something but cant seem to figure out what... can anybody help me?

**SOLUTION**
Add the lib64 directory to LDFLAGS (commands have been updated).

Comment: ["Unable to find remote helper for 'https'" during git clone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8329485) on Stack Overflow. You have to build cURL with HTTPS, and then build Git with cURL support. In addition, I've found you can configure git with `--wth-curl`, but it will silently fail if something is wrong. You must inspect `config.log` to look for failures. Also see [Are there any hints with building Git with HTTP and HTTPS helpers](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-08/0114.html) on the cURL mailing list.

Comment: As you see in the OP, I have succesfully build curl with https. Thank you for referring me to the config.log, I was not aware of it siletnly failing.

The post is updated with the solution, which was adding the lib64 directory to LDFlags.

Comment: You should add an answer to your question; and not edit the question and insert an answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION Add the lib64 directory to LDFLAGS (commands have been updated).